# A Null Point Exception when use openapi maven generator

Tags: java, maven, openapi

I did the validation in the [YAML file](https://github.com/platformsh/platformsh-client-java/blob/master/src/main/resources/api.yaml) and it passes, however, when I try to generate the code from this YAML file API it returns the error below:

```
  Exception: null
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processOperation (DefaultGenerator.java:1204)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processPaths (DefaultGenerator.java:1098)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateApis (DefaultGenerator.java:556)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:1008)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:746)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.fromRequestBodyToFormParameters (DefaultCodegen.java:5458)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.fromOperation (DefaultCodegen.java:3506)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.fromOperation (AbstractJavaCodegen.java:1226)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processOperation (DefaultGenerator.java:1172)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processPaths (DefaultGenerator.java:1098)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateApis (DefaultGenerator.java:556)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:1008)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:746)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

openapi-generator version

- 4.3.1

OpenAPI declaration file content or url

The URL code: https://github.com/platformsh/platformsh-client-java/blob/master/src/main/resources/api.yaml

Command line used for generation

On this project source code: https://github.com/platformsh/platformsh-client-java
We run this command:

```
mvn clean package
```

Steps to reproduce

```
git clone git@github.com:platformsh/platformsh-client-java.git
cd platformsh-client-java
mvn clean package
```

Comment: I've created a issue on the github: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/6562

Comment: I am having the same problem with the open-api-generator npm package